# Did 50% Americans believe "the movie and television industries are pretty much run by Jews" in 1964?

Tags: united-states, movies

Joel Stein wrote an article on [Los Angeles Times](http://articles.latimes.com/2008/dec/19/opinion/oe-stein19) in which he claims:

> I have never been so upset by a poll in my life. Only 22% of Americans now believe "the movie and television industries are pretty much run by Jews," down from nearly 50% in 1964. The Anti-Defamation League, which released the poll results last month, sees in these numbers a victory against stereotyping. Actually, it just shows how dumb America has gotten. Jews totally run Hollywood.

Is it true that 50% of Americans believed that "the movie and television industries are pretty much run by Jews" in 1964?

Comment: _"Is it true that 50% of Americans believed...?"_ How could we possibly know? You could ask if there's any basis to make that statement, and what is such basis; but could we really know if any individual or amount of population, in any moment in history, believed something? *I skeptizise that!*

Comment: For those wondering, the op-ed seems to be humorous in tone, but making this particular claim seriously.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Contrary to another answer, the 1964 survey was not run by a special interest group.  Instead, it was designed by the Survey Research Center, University of California, Berkeley and conducted by the National Opinion Research Center (NORC), University of Chicago.

The [National Opinion Research Center Fiftieth Anniversary Report](http://www.norc.org/PDFs/Annual%20Reports/NORC_Annual_Report_1991.pdf) 1991 states:

> during the 1960s NORC worked with the Survey Research Center
>   at the University of California investigating anti-
>   Semitism as part of its Research Program on
>   Patterns of American Prejudice. Data from the
>   California program were used to develop a
>   picture of anti-Semitism in the United States, and
>   to understand the form such prejudice took
>   among persons of different demographic groups

The survey was published in [The tenacity of prejudice: anti-Semitism in contemporary America](https://books.google.com/books?id=c4EmAQAAMAAJ&dq=%22The+tenacity+of+prejudice%3A+anti-Semitism+in+contemporary+America%22&focus=searchwithinvolume&q=%22movie+and+television+industries+are%22) (referenced in the above NORC report).

The survey [found](https://books.google.com/books?id=O8JLU1og8ooC&pg=PR15&dq=47%20percent%20%22non-jews%22%20movies%20and%20television%20industries%20are%20run%20by%20jews&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiDsdri7vjQAhVHx1QKHX1yDosQ6AEIGjAA#v=onepage&q=47%20percent%20%22non-jews%22%20movies%20and%20television%20industries%20are%20run%20by%20jews&f=false) that 47% of **non-Jews** agreed with the statement "the movie and television industries are pretty much run by Jews". 21% disagreed and 32% didn't know.

In other words, the survey was not representative of all Americans, it excluded Jews.

Comment: Excluding Jews doesn't make the survey too far off from total population, as there aren't all that statistically many Jews in USA. [1.4% in 2001](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/American_Jews#Demographics)

Comment: @user5341 Pew says "surveys in the 1950s and 1960s consistently found that between 3% and 4% of American adults said their religion was Jewish" http://www.pewresearch.org/fact-tank/2013/10/02/how-many-jews-are-there-in-the-united-states/ and of course others consider themselves Jews in the ethnic sense.

Comment: @DavePhD - wow, that was unexpected. But still, unless my back of the envelope math is off, 47% of 96% would make for **45.12%**. Not that much of a difference from 47% as to render the results meaningfully wrong to any degree - and i'm using the worst case estimate where 100% of Jews disagreed with the statement, which isn't a given.

Comment: @user5341 right, it wouldn't change much.

Answer (score 0):

Joel Stein gives a reference to his claims:

> The Anti-Defamation League, which released the poll results last month

Note: "Last month" = November 2008 - this is an old claim.

Here is the [press release for that poll](http://archive.adl.org/nr/exeres/c8544658-f7ae-4b01-a07c-19cb23299328,0b1623ca-d5a4-465d-a369-df6e8679cd9e,frameless.html):

> When ADL conducted its first survey on anti-Semitic attitudes in 1964, nearly half of all Americans believed that the television and film industries were run by Jews.

It links to a graph to illustrate it:

[image: Graph showing 47% agreement in 1964]

The graph shows the "nearly half" corresponds to 47%.

Surveys have limited power. Surveys run by special-interest groups, which don't show error bars, should be treated carefully.

Comment: It's unfair to try to discredit a 1964 survey just because a 2008 graphic doesn't show the error bars.  The 1964 survey was not run by a special interest group; it was run by the University of Chicago and it was designed by University of California, Berkeley.  The question is about the 1964 survey.

Comment: @DavePhD: it's weird that the ADL explicitly claims it conducted the 1964 survey. Poor organisational memory, or did they have some other involvement?

Comment: I think they did provide funding, but didn't run or design  the study.  The lead author was Gertrude Jaegar, a Berkeley feminist who appears to have been Christian. http://www.findagrave.com/cgi-bin/fg.cgi?page=pv&GRid=88959503&PIpi=65917908